# Get user/account name which has installed app from Google Play

Tags: android, user-accounts, android-package-managers

I khow that is very easy to load list of istalled packages:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> applications = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
for (ApplicationInfo info : applications) {
        Log.d(TAG, info.packageName + " : " + info.uid);
    }
}
```

But on my device I have several Google Accounts. How can I determine which account used to install an app?
Is it possible to use `uid` for that ?
Exact question: How to detect who (user) install what (app)?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html

Comment: Add where is the link between account and intalled package?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  If you're just trying to find out who installed what, that might not be possible.

Comment: Yes, the question is who install what